# Why copy rotation constraint does not register actual rotation?

Tags: constraints

I have an example, where I need eyelids of the character to follow eye movement. Eyelids movement is based on blendshapes driven by X and Z axis of an eyebone. Whenever I set target bone for eyes to look at eyelids will not follow, because eye bone that is looking at (track to constraint) target does not "produce" any rotation information, despite it's obviously rotating. How do I workaround this?

Comment: hello, could you please show some screenshots? It would help to understand your problem

Comment: or provide your blend file...

Comment: Sure. Here you have a cube pointing to an empty. Notice, that if you move an empty rotation information of a cube will not change

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WWi3mKiPpEFh3n5lN_RW1wM7OS2sdcKJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

of course not, because you just added a "track to" contraints to your cube, which tracks to your empty. So the cube rotates in that way, that it tracks to the empty.
And there is no copy rotation constraint at all...

Comment: so, is there a way to retrieve rotation information from it?

Comment: can you provide your eyelid-blend file?

Comment: This is not the proper file, but principle is the same. I would also like to point out, that even if you use copy rotation constraint a constrained object will not inherit rotation information aswell unfortunately.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WWi3mKiPpEFh3n5lN_RW1wM7OS2sdcKJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it will, but of course, track to and copy rotation influence each other....

Comment: is this what you want to achieve? https://youtu.be/xSHaXTstxcs

Comment: I want this cuboid to produce rotation information so I could use it as driver for something. See this, that if you move target, and cuboid will rotate along it will not have any rotation information in transform tab.

Comment: ok, now i think i got it. Yes, you don't see it in the transformation tab, but if you use copy rotation constraint, it copies it. So if you do this to your eyelid, it will rotate with it.

Comment: yes, but eyelid is a blendshape so I cant use copy rotation with it :)

Comment: do you mean a shape key? if yes, then this shapekey is owned by an object which you can give the copy rotation constraint. or what is a blendershape?

Comment: blendshape is a shapekey